# Dynamic IIF in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a metadata-driven Spark Transformation Engine. That performs a set of operations on the data frames stored in the Scala Map[String, DataFrame].
I have a scenario where user have IIF (ternary if) to be implemented:

```
if(<condition>,<iftrue>,<iffalse>)
if(cola=1,to_date(colb),null)
```

My Approach: I am making use of where clause to evaluate the  and UDF to return and perform any functions if any like (to_date. to_decimal etc). For the above code:

```
dfMap(source).where(<condn>).withColumn("<tarCol>",CustomUDF(<iftrue>))
```

I have read UDF impacts the performance in Spark and I am facing the same. Please suggest any alternative for the same.

Comment: Something told me that working more explicit is the better way with Spark. There is the monad academic school that hardly anyone can follows, and others who get a contract on this meta-driven approach. The latter works partially only. Note the DB manuals work with more explicit coding. To a degree it works, but...

Comment: whats the issue with `case...when...otherwise`?

Comment: try this - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#if